# VBA Code Using Table References instead of Column Numbers

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I have a few macros that use column numbers in the code, however, whenever, I add or move columns I need to revise the code.  I have other code that I've successfully used table references, but I'm struggling with this one. Understandably, I keep getting a Type Mismatch error when using the Table Reference on the **Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, FL_UT).Select** rows, but I'm not sure what would work. Here's my attempt using Table References:

```
Sub QC_DesignIssued2()

Dim strText As String
Dim MyDate As Date
Dim cl As Range

strText = Clipboard 'runs Function Clipboard to define copied text as 'Clipboard'
MyDate = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yy") 'defines MyDate as Today

'SET TABLE REFERENCE AREA
   Set rData = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Tracker").ListObjects("Table_COMPOSITE")

'declare object variable to column heading
Dim FL_UT As Range 'FL UT (Column heading)
Dim FL_Notes As Range 'FL Design Notes (FET)
Dim FL_Permit As Range 'FL Permit Required (FET)


Set FL_UT = rData.ListColumns("FL UT").Range
Set FL_Notes = rData.ListColumns("FL Design Notes (FET)").Range
Set FL_Permit = rData.ListColumns("FL Permit Required (FET)").Range


Dim FD_UT As Range 'FD UT = Column heading /column #64
Dim FD_Notes As Range 'FD Design Notes (FET)/ #104
Dim FD_Permit As Range 'FD Permit Required (FET) / #109

Set FD_UT = rData.ListColumns("FD UT (FET)").Range
Set FD_Notes = rData.ListColumns("FD Design Notes (FET)").Range
Set FD_Permit = rData.ListColumns("FD Permit Required (FET)").Range


With Worksheets("Tracker").Cells
   Set cl = .Find(strText, After:=.Range("A2"), LookIn:=xlValues)
     If Not cl Is Nothing Then
      cl.Select
      Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, FL_UT).Select 'FL UT (column heading)
  Else
    MsgBox strText & " Not Found"
      End If
End With


'If FL_UT number matches StrText then populate other FL related fields
   If ActiveCell = strText Then

   Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, FL_Notes).Select 'FL Design Notes (FET)
   ActiveCell.Value = MyDate & " Issued" & Chr(10) & ActiveCell.Value
   Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, FL_IssuedACD).Value = MyDate 'FL Design Issued ACD (FET)
 'Ask if permit is needed for FL Project and populate with UserInput
    Dim strInput_FL As String
    Dim IsPermit_FL As String
   
    IsPermit_FL = MsgBox("Is a permit required for FL UT?", vbYesNo)
           
    If IsPermit_FL = vbNo Then
        Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, FL_Permit).Value = "No" 'FL Permit Required (FET)
        Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, FL_PermitACD).Value = "01/01/01" 'FL Permit Received ACD (FET)
    Else 'IsPermit = Yes
            Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, FL_Permit).Value = "Yes"
            
            strInput_FL = InputBox("What is date of permit ECD for FL UT?")
            Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, FL_PermitECD).Value = strInput_FL
    End If

Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, FL_UT).Select 'Reset column numbering by selecting FL UT column again

    Else  'If Project Number (StrText) doesn't match a number in the FL UT column, populate FD UT columns

         Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, FD_Notes).Select 'FD Design Notes (FET)
         ActiveCell.Value = MyDate & " Issued" & Chr(10) & ActiveCell.Value
         Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, FD_IssuedACD).Value = MyDate 'Design Issued ACD (FET)
    End If

  End If
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to approach this without using `ActiveCell`:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rData As ListObject, FL_UT As Long, FL_Notes As Long, FL_Permit As Long
    Dim f As Range, rw As Range
    
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Tracker")
    Set rData = ws.ListObjects("Table_COMPOSITE")
    
    'grab the list column indexes
    FL_UT = rData.ListColumns("FL UT").Index 'column # in table
    FL_Notes = rData.ListColumns("FL Design Notes (FET)").Index
    FL_Permit = rData.ListColumns("FL Permit Required (FET)").Index
    
    
    'does this not need to search a specific range/column?
    Set f = ws.Cells.Find("blahblah", After:=ws.Range("A2"), _
                          LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) 'or xlPart
    
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        'get the listobject row for the found cell
        Set rw = Application.Intersect(f.EntireRow, rData.DataBodyRange)
        'use the column indexes to update the row
        rw.Cells(FL_UT) = "A"
        rw.Cells(FL_Notes) = "B"
        rw.Cells(FL_Permit) = "C"
    Else
        MsgBox "Not found"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked great!  I'm so excited that I won't have to revise my macros every time someone (usually me) moves or adds a column.  I'm a self-taught VBA user and I learned a lot from this one.  Thanks so much.